Background color not changing in isActive NavLink React JavaScript
The Background color of the selected list item isn't changing, only the text color is changing to white.
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { MyContext } from "./links/MyContext.jsx";
import { useContext } from "react";

export default function HeaderLists() {
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(MyContext);

  const activeLink = `bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-800 to-blue-800 text-white `;
  const normalLink = `hover:text-white hover:border-none ${
    isDarkMode
      ? "text-white from-blue-950 to-cyan-900"
      : "text-stone-600 border-stone-600"
  }`;

  return (
    <ul className="mt-10 text-center">
      <NavLink
        to="/"
        className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
      >
        <li className="border-b-2 border-b-stone-500 p-5 hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-600">
          {t("tasks")}{" "}
        </li>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink
        to="/Calendar"
        className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
      >
        <li className="border-b-2 border-b-stone-500 p-5 hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-600">
          {t("calendar")}
        </li>
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink
        to="/Settings"
        className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeLink : normalLink)}
      >
        <li className="border-b-2 border-b-stone-500 p-5 hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-600">
          {t("settings")}{" "}
        </li>
      </NavLink>
    </ul>
  );
}

When I select a list item such as Tasks, or Calendar, the selected item color is then changed to white, but the background color remains the same. It won't change to the gradient I specified in activeLink const. I would like to know how I can fix it.

For a sanity check, try applying the active style to every link without the ternary lilke so  <NavLink         to="/Calendar"         className={activeLink}       >  if that still doesn't work then you know it's a CSS issue.

You are applying the style to the NavLink component, e.g. the anchor tag, instead of the li element which still has its own CSS styling that includes a background color.
Use the children function prop to access the link's isActive prop and apply the CSS to the li element.
Example Implementation:
const links = [
  {
    to: "/",
    key: "tasks"
  },
  {
    to: "/Calendar",
    key: "calendar"
  },
  {
    to: "/Settings",
    key: "settings"
  },
];

export default function HeaderLists() {
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(MyContext);

  const activeLink = `bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-800 to-blue-800 text-white `;
  const normalLink = `hover:text-white hover:border-none ${
    isDarkMode
      ? "text-white from-blue-950 to-cyan-900"
      : "text-stone-600 border-stone-600"
  }`;

  const getStyle = ({ isActive }) => [
    "border-b-2 border-b-stone-500 p-5 hover:bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-600",
    isActive ? activeLink : normalLink
  ].join(" ");

  return (
    <ul className="mt-10 text-center">
      {links.map(({ to, key }) => (
        <NavLink key={to} to={to}>
          {({ isActive }) => (
            <li className={getStyle({ isActive })}>
              {t(key)}{" "}
            </li>
          )}
        </NavLink>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

